# Notify another user when a question is posted

Tags: support, asking-questions, notifications

Ok, this is my scenario, I have a question regarding a plugin and I posted in Stack Overflow and I know a user who can answer this because he is the author of the same plugin. Is there any way I can notify the user?

I know tagging another user to a question/answer/comment without their concern will create a mess. But is there any way?

Comment: Got it. I couldn't find it when I searched. Thanks.. :-)